# Loop through two directories using for loop python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am trying to compare two pdfs. My approach consists of converting both pdfs and comparing the images of corresponding pages. I initially wrote a simple code which compares two images which corresponds to the first code below, which works without a glitch.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

original = cv2.imread("image_old/imageOld_1.jpg")
image_to_compare = cv2.imread("image_new/imageNew_1.jpg")

image1 = original.shape
image2 = image_to_compare.shape

if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:
    print("The images have same size and channels")
    difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
    r, g, b = cv2.split(difference)  
    cv2.imshow("difference", cv2.resize( difference, None, fx=0.3, fy=0.3))
    
    print(cv2.countNonZero(b))
    if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
       print("The images are completely Equal")
    else:
        print("The images are not equal")

sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)
 
print("Keypoints of 1st image: " + str(len(kp_1)))
print("Keypoints of 2nd image: " + str(len(kp_2)))

index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
search_params = dict()
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)

good_points = []
for m, n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.6*n.distance:
        good_points.append(m)
print('The images have %d %s' %(len(good_points),"good points matches"))

if len(kp_1) <= len(kp_2):
    number_keypoints = len(kp_1)
else:
    number_keypoints = len(kp_2)

percentage_similarity = len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100
print('Similarity %d %s' %(round((percentage_similarity)),"%\n"))
result = cv2.drawMatches(original, kp_1, image_to_compare, kp_2, good_points, None)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Next I added a for loop to do same as the above code but for 5 images. The idea is that it gets the imageOld_1.jpg and compares with imageNew_1.jpg, imageOld_2.jpg and compares with imageNew_2.jpg... The code below compares the first pair of images imageOld_1.jpg and imageNew_1.jpg(and I get results) but for some reason it doesn't continue looping through the other images i.e comparing imageOld_2.jpg and imageNew_2.jpg, comparing imageOld_3.jpg and imageNew_3.jpg... I am getting the error below, what am I doing wrong?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a=[1,2,3,4,5]
b=[1,2,3,4,5]

for i in a:
    original = cv2.imread("image_old/imageOld_"+str(i)+".jpg")
    for j in b:
        if a == b :
            image_to_compare = cv2.imread("image_new/imageNew_"+str(j)+".jpg")
            image1 = original.shape
            image2 = image_to_compare.shape

            if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:
                print("The images "+str(i)+" have same size and channels")

                print("Diffing page "+str(i)+" and "+str(j)+" of both pdfs")
                difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
                r, g, b = cv2.split(difference)  
                cv2.imshow("difference", cv2.resize( difference, None, fx=0.3, fy=0.3))
                
                if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
                    print("The images are completely Equal")
                else:
                    print("The images are not equal")

            sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
            kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
            kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)
            
            print("Keypoints of 1st image: " + str(len(kp_1)))
            print("Keypoints of 2nd image: " + str(len(kp_2)))

            index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
            search_params = dict()
            flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

            matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)

            good_points = []
            for m, n in matches:
                if m.distance < 0.6*n.distance:
                    good_points.append(m)
            
            print('The images have %d %s' %(len(good_points),"good points matches"))

            if len(kp_1) <= len(kp_2):
                number_keypoints = len(kp_1)
            else:
                number_keypoints = len(kp_2)

            percentage_similarity = len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100
            print('Similarity %d %s' %(round((percentage_similarity)),"%\n"))


            result = cv2.drawMatches(original, kp_1, image_to_compare, kp_2, good_points, None)
  
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Error**

```
 DeprecationWarning: elementwise comparison failed; this will raise an error in the future.
  if a == b :
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine both lists for comparing the same images.

You can use `zip`:

```py
import cv2

a = [1]
b = [1]

for i, j in zip(a, b):
    original = cv2.imread("image_old/imageOld_" + str(i) + ".jpg")
    image_to_compare = cv2.imread("image_new/imageNew_" + str(j) + ".jpg")
    image1 = original.shape
    image2 = image_to_compare.shape

    if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:
        print("The images " + str(i) + " have same size and channels")
        print("Diffing page " + str(i) + " and " + str(j) + " of both pdfs")
        difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
        r, g, b = cv2.split(difference)
        cv2.imshow("difference", cv2.resize(difference, None, fx=0.3, fy=0.3))

        if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
            print("The images are completely Equal")
        else:
            print("The images are not equal")

    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
    kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)

    print("Keypoints of 1st image: " + str(len(kp_1)))
    print("Keypoints of 2nd image: " + str(len(kp_2)))

    index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
    search_params = dict()
    flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

    matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)

    good_points = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.6 * n.distance:
            good_points.append(m)

    print('The images have %d %s' % (len(good_points), "good points matches"))

    if len(kp_1) <= len(kp_2):
        number_keypoints = len(kp_1)
    else:
        number_keypoints = len(kp_2)

    percentage_similarity = len(good_points) / number_keypoints * 100
    print('Similarity %d %s' % (round((percentage_similarity)), "%\n"))

    result = cv2.drawMatches(original, kp_1, image_to_compare, kp_2, good_points, None)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

```py
The images 1 have same size and channels
Diffing page 1 and 1 of both pdfs
The images are completely Equal
Keypoints of 1st image: 8066
Keypoints of 2nd image: 8066
The images have 3117 good points matches
Similarity 39 %
```

Below is the sample I used for both `imagesNew_1.jpg` and `imagesOld_1.jpg`

[image]